# Installing pfSense on intel server

Tags: pfsense

I have an intel server as a router.
I want to migrate from windows routing to pfSense.

I am trying to format my server with ISO file over IPMI connection.
When I load the ISO, I get this:

[image]

Is it even possible to install pfSense on my hardware?
I tried to install from [this](https://www.pfsense.org/download/) location, Architecture:AMD64 (64bit) with CD image.

I didn't find any specific reference for Intel, just to use this for 64bit systems.

So I have left it running and eventually got this: [image]

I found [this](https://forum.netgate.com/topic/84368/btx-halted-error-with-2-2-2/18) tread, and [this](https://redmine.pfsense.org/issues/4718) bug report.
But no solution.

Comment: What you see is a loading spinner in ASCII: /, -, \, |. Your console connection apparently cannot transmit this correctly.

Comment: Which issue and image did you download?

Comment: @MohammadRezamoeini I used 2.4.5-p1 version, with AMD64 (64bit) and CD image (ISO). I tried New York, Frankfurt and Singapore. All failed.

Comment: @DanielB Thank you. What can I do? My IPMI is Tyan. We tried for example centos7 ISO and it worked with no problem.

Comment: Your system is not compatible with your Hardware , Best solution is passed kernel parameter to your OS and find exact issue , for this propose press ESC while on "Welcome to pfSense" boot screen. Type boot -v and hit ENTER. it boot OS in verbose mode

Comment: @MohammadRezamoeini I don't get a welcome to pfSense  window. 
I skip from Tyan window to storage raid config to the window you see in the question.

Comment: Tou issue is freebsd kernel not your ipmi

Comment: I very much doubt there’s any real incompatibility here, just the console connection problem. The loading spinner is part of the bootloader, before the BSD kernel even starts. I suggest installing it “in-person”.

Comment: @DanielB installing with physical bootable device got the same error. 
It looks like a bug. Went down to lower version fixed it.